# Python shelve and random iterator

Tags: python, iterator, iterable, shelve

I want to create an iterator for a shelve key-value store that can be used multiple times but each time returns values in a different order. A shelve iterator returns values in a random order but the order doesn't change on each invocation. Here is an example:

import shelve

```
# store key-value pairs with shelve
d = shelve.open('kv_store')
kv = {'a': 9, 'b': 8, 'c': 7, 'd': 6}
for key in kv.keys():
    d[str(key)] = kv[key]
d.close()

# create iterator for key-value store
d = shelve.open('kv_store')
iterator = iter(d)
for i in iterator:
    print(i)
d.close()

> b
> d
> a
> c

# repeat create iterator for key-value store
d = shelve.open('kv_store')
iterator = iter(d)
for i in iterator:
    print(i)
d.close()

> b
> d
> a
> c
```

How can I get the shelve iterator to return values in a different order each time (eg. using random.shuffle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call shuffle you need to make iterator a list:

```
iterator = list(d)
shuffle(iterator)
```

`shuffle` expects a list so you need to pass it one by call list on `d` to get a list of keys.

You also don't need to call `iter` unless you actually want an iterator, you could just iterate over `d`.

Comment: Thanks! Getting the hang of iterators!

Answer (score 1):

You just get the non-defined order from the underlying dict implementation.  Try this, will work for any dict-like:

```
def random_dict_iter(x):
    _x = x.keys()
    random.shuffle(_x)
    return _x           # or if you like: return iter(_x)
```

EDIT: As @Padraic Cunningham pointed out in the comment, [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30370054/450517) is the better one. Not only does it also work in Python3, it is also more concise.

Comment: `list(d)` is exactly what your code is doing and will work on both python 2 and 3, this won't work on python3